# Getting data from Firebase to Fragment

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-fragments, firebase-realtime-database

I have one Tabbed Activity which has 3 Fragments. In every Fragment I need to display some data from my realtime firebase database. So i thought that instead of connecting to database in every Fragment, I would retrieve data to static variable inside my tabbed activity, and then display this data calling this variable from every Fragment. But when I try to set my text to data from Firebase it shows an error, because in that moment, my static variable is "null". How do I make sure that that first I retrieve the data to my variable and then set my text. Because right now, my tabbed activity has ValueEventListener inside the onCreate method, and I am trying to set the TextView, from OnCreateView inside Fragments. I made some tests and realized, that the onCreate method inside of Tabbed Activity is called first, but onCreateView from my Fragment is called shortly after when the data isn't retrieved yet.

Comment: Could you include the part of code you comment? You just have to set the data, from the activity to each fragment, when the firebase request callback is called.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get Reference of your fragments like below

```
ExampleFragment myFragment = (ExampleFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(ExampleFragment.TAG);
```

And then when the data finished loading. Send it like below code.

```
myfragment.sendDataToFragment(myData);
```

i hope it helps.

Also you can use interfaces to communicate between Activity and fragments.